# Did Thor really intend to murder Captain America?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, captain-america, thor-marvel

During [Avengers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0848228/), Captain America interrupts Thor and Iron Man in the middle of their fight after Loki escapes, Thor's immediate response is to attack Captain America.

Captain America survives thanks to his vibranium shield.

But did Thor know Cap could take the hit or did he really intend to murder this polite stranger for interrupting his fight?